# Digitally signing .bin file using a certificate

Tags: certificates, signature

I have .bin file and i need to digitally sign it to ensure that it is given by me and trusted one. How can i digitally sign? In microsoft i am using signtool.exe to sign which signs by using a certificate.

Comment: Even I have the same requirement. I can use signtool in Windows, which can also sign scripts like PowerShell. But how to do this in Linux?

Answer (score 0):

I would use GPG for that. For details, read [this guide](http://www.tutonics.com/2012/11/gpg-encryption-guide-part-3-digital.html#.Uc1Grtdl4_8). GPG can be used to generate a digital signature detached from the binary file. It can be checked against a binary using your public key, therefore ensuring that the file is exactly the same file as the one that has been used to generate the signature with your private key. Read the "Using A Detached Digital Signature" section in the above document.